# Detect if a text encrypted using AES CBC is padded or not

Tags: encryption, cryptography, cypher, aes

I have some data which could be encrypted using `AES/CBC/NoPadding` or `AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding`.

I want to decrypt that data. So need to decide on which algo to use for decryption. Based on the data, is it possible to figure out if the data which is encrypted is padded or not?
or is there any other solution to this?

Comment: No, it's not possible without knowing at least the length of the plaintext a priori.

Comment: Decrypt using NoPadding.  Then look at the end of the decrypted text.  If there is padding, that is where it will appear.  You can examine it to determine what sort of padding was used on the encryption side.  If it was encrypted with NoPadding originally, then the decrypted text will finish normally with no strange characters from the padding added at the end.

Comment: @rossum: There is no way to distinguish a padded plaintext with an unpadded plaintext that just happened to have the same characters, unless by "no strange characters" you mean something like ASCII text.

Comment: If the NoPadding decrypted text ends with 0x03 0x03 0x03 then it is very likely 3 bytes of PKCS7 padding.  If it ends with 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 ... then it is very likely PaddingZeros.  You cannot be absolutely sure, but you can make an educated guess.

Answer (score 1):

The comments are correct, however, there is a better way on the programming side; the [bad padding exception](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/crypto/BadPaddingException.html) ( assuming the Java)

```java
try {
     
     //do the decryption....

    } catch (javax.crypto.BadPaddingException e ){
          Sytem.out.Println("It is not PKCS#7 padding")
          e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
```

If you get an exception, then it is not PKCS#7. If you don't get an exception then you have a 1/256 probability that it is not PKCS#7 but your file ended with the byte `0x01`. There are other cases like your file ended with `0x0202`, however, the probability is very low, and lower than this for other cases, too. The easiest is to try more than one file.

Why I did say `PKCS#7 padding` is simple. Although Java says PKCS#5 padding it is not, it is PKCS#7 padding that supersedes #5. #5 was designed for 64-bit block-sized ciphers like DES and #7 was designed up to 256-bytes, where AES has a 128-bit block size.

---

Note that the probability is assuming that the files are random, not regular text files.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Do you know why in few cases the BadPaddingException is not thrown? In my case, I have lot of data to decrypt. I have followed your suggestion and observed that in few cases the decrypted data is a byte smaller than what it should be.

Comment: Did you read the first paragraph? is it not clear? If the last byte is `0x01` then it is valid padding for PKCS#7. in 1/256 cases ( if the data uniform random ) you will get valid padding though the data is not paddded.